# Solution to NB JUnit auto-closing program after 6 minutes

Tags: java, netbeans, junit, jelly, jemmy

I'm using NB JUnit with JUnit 4, Jelly Tools, and Jemmy.

I have a pretty standard setup in the suite() function, following the tutorials provided.

```
public static Test suite() {
    // run tests with specific configuration
    NbModuleSuite.Configuration conf =
            NbModuleSuite.createConfiguration(Tester.class).
            clusters(".*").
            enableModules(".*");
    conf = conf.addTest("test1", "test2", "test3");
    return NbModuleSuite.create(conf);
}
```

(see http://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-test.html if you want more details on the tutorial I mentioned)

What seems to be happening is, around the 6 minute mark, no matter what the tester should be doing, it closes the NetBeans window.

Right before it closes, the tester skips ahead to try and cram in all the tests it has yet to finish.

In my case, I am calling

```
new Timeout("pausing", 1000).sleep();
```

in a while loop, which waits for a certain function call to return true. But, around 5:30 into the test, the tester moves on from this function, finishes the other tests, and closes the window.

I'm unsure if there are time limits for each individual test, or if there is a timeout for the tester altogether. But, I do notice that if I add another test or two with a long pause or enough random clicks and button pushes to last a few minutes, the tester still closes right around 6 minutes. The time is never exactly the same, but it ranges right around there.

I've tried a few different ways of pausing the tester, with no luck. And I can't find anything to help online as these are not heavily publicized. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default the timeout period should be set to 0L (http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html#timeout())
maybe try to change the timeout parameter to a very huge value.

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-31002.html&highlight=

it looks like you can set the timeout in your Per-user Project Properties (private.properties) or project.properties file by setting

```
test.timeout=3600000
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I had found test.timeout in the .xml file, but changing that didn't help. However, adding it to project.properties seems to have done the trick.

I'm not sure why because the default is 10 minutes, and my tester stopped at 6, but thank you!

Comment: you know that the timeout time is for all your tests? Maybe when your other tests also need a few minutes you can run out of time. 
The Time in Java is also not really exact but I don't believe that this can cause a loss of a few minutes =/

Comment: My tester seemed to run the first 7/10 tests. Then the 8th is supposed to take a few hours, but a few mins in it moves on to the next tests and closes itself at 6mins. Even if I add more tests and put in extra timeouts, it still manages to accomplish (what it thinks is) everything by 6 mins.

Adding the test.timeout=xxxx to project.properties stops the tester from closing itself so soon, but the timing is still weird.

Adding 3600000 (1 hour) results in the tester closing itself in about 30 minutes, following the same behavior I mentioned above. The default 10 min resulted in 6 mins.

Comment: One thing that could possibly be the reason could be that there is also an value how long a single test can take maybe this value is by default set to half the timeout time. But that really is just speculation.